# using "1.6.1" "1.10.2" versions of jquery together in the same page does not working with noConflict

Tags: jquery

I did all versions of what the "https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/" says but no result!

I made a php script which uses file_get_contents() to pull 2 different jquery pages and used str_replace() to change the entire code as every version but none of them is working as u can see (with chrome browser: view-source:http://etkinlik.me-how.tk/test.php) both scripts are working their selfs but when i collect'em together one of it brakes!

Answer (score -1):

I think the real issue here is that you have two documents in a single HTML page. That is unacceptable according to the standard.

You should serve the information separately.

That said, what do you need multiple jQuery versions for anyways?

Comment: I am aware! i tried that kinds of http://etkinlik.me-how.tk/test2.txt too!..
none of'em works...

i just need **flipCounter 1.2** by bloggingsquared.com and **FlipClock.js 0.4.0** whichs by flipclockjs.com works together... which are using **jquery v.1.10.2**(flipclockjs) and **v.1.6.1**(flipcounter) thats all... check out examples that i gave before.

Comment: i dont know why but i cant reach test2.txt (yes! its on the server which i pointed!) try to see test2.php's source...